# ModelAttribute gets overwritten on submit spring 3.0

Tags: spring

In my controller I have following function

```
@ModelAttribute("ABeanCV")
public AClass getCommand_Class()
{
AClass ABean=new AClass();
ABean.setQuestions(new AutoPopulatingList(ABean.class));
return ABean;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/AFormCV.htm")
protected String showNameForm(@ModelAttribute("ABeanCV") AClass command_Class,ModelMap model)
{
command_Class.getQuestions().get(52).setAns("123456789");
command_Class.getQuestions().get(52).setPrevAns("987654321");
model.addAttribute("Question",as);
command_Class.getQuestions().get(52).setCurrAns("435678543");
model.addAttribute("Question",as);
return "ACV";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/submitQuestionForm.htm")
protected String submitNameForm(@ModelAttribute("ABeanCV") AClass commandClassCV, ModelMap model )
{
System.out.println("Ans wer to q 52 : "+commandClassCV.getQuestions().get(52).getAns());
System.out.println("PREv Ans wer to q 52 : "+commandClassCV.getQuestions().get(52).getPrevAns());
System.out.println("PREv Ans wer to q 52 : "+commandClassCV.getQuestions().get(52).getCurrAns());
model.addAttribute("Question",as);
return "ACV";
}
```

My JSP

```
<form:form method="post" name="classForm" id="classForm" modelAttribute="ABeanCV" commandName="ABeanCV" action="submitQuestionForm.htm">

 here I have only 2 input values " ans and prevAns " but in my showNameForm function I am setting values for  " ans , prevAns and currAns " input values
```

When I run the project in the form 2 fileds are displayed fine. After the form is submited when I try and print the 3 values in my submitNameForm function only those values get printed which are displayed on the form ie. " ans and prevAns ". The third value " currAns " whch was set in the showNameForm function prints null.

Is the modelAttribute getting overwritten when the form is submitted? How can I still get the value of " currAns " ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you submit the form first ModelAttribute will get overridden by getCommand_Class() method and then Question field in AClass will get set with the values displyed on the UI. This is because all methods in the controller annoted with ModelAttribute gets executed in order to initiaze Model object.

You can get away with it by

- removing getCommand_Class() method and ModelAttribute AClass from showNameForm method.
- create new object of AClass with required data in it and set AClass in the ModelMap.
- Return the ModelAndView object so that JSP will get the Model object.